# creating a dataframe with all combinations of columns and count the rows that are not 0 and NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, combinations

I am trying to create a dataframe with all combinations of columns and count the rows that are both not 0 or NaN

The Dataframe that I have look like below:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | NaN | 30 |
| 0 | -20 | 10 |

the final output would look like below:

| variable_1 | variable_2 | count_rows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0 |
| b | c | 1 |

The Final output would have all the combinations of the original columns,

and the 'count_rows' column will go through the original dataframe and count the rows of each combinations that are not 0 & NaN

In addition I want to make sure that the duplicates are allowed, and what I mean by this is that

For example,

| variable_1 | variable_2 | count_rows |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 0 |
| b | a | 0 |

The values and combinations are the same, just the orders are different, but I still want to keep them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
def fn(x):
    return (
        df[[x["0_x"], x["0_y"]]]
        .apply(lambda y: (y.notna() & y.ne(0)).all(), axis=1)
        .sum()
    )


df_out = df.columns.to_frame().merge(df.columns.to_frame(), how="cross")
df_out = df_out[df_out["0_x"] != df_out["0_y"]]
df_out["count_rows"] = df_out.apply(fn, axis=1)
print(df_out.rename(columns={"0_x": "variable_1", "0_y": "variable_2"}))
```

Prints:

```
  variable_1 variable_2  count_rows
1          a          b           0
2          a          c           1
3          b          a           0
5          b          c           1
6          c          a           1
7          c          b           1
```